# Cannot run program " xx/sdk//tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: android, ubuntu, adt, apt

I have installed android SDK and android eclipse plugin successfully on Ubuntu 12.10.
I created the AVD in eclipse, and now it's not running. This is the output error I receive when I run the AVD:it tips:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'avd'
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/sancai/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/sdk//tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I find information via google, everyone says this is because my system version is 64, while the adt only support 32, to install: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs, when I installed the 32-bit library, other problems arise such as the library file association to other libraries, but has no other library files are fully，it tips:

```
sancai@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

sancai@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs-multiarch is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ia32-libs-multiarch' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Does `/home/sancai/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/sdk//tools/emulator` run from command line?

Comment: not ,it is in eclipse create avd

Comment: it doesn't matter if you created the AVD in eclipse, just try the command line

Comment: try command line  create AVD?oK, i try do it

Comment: no ok, i dont create avd via the command line

Answer (score 30):

This should help:

Go to xx/sdk/tools and run:

```
mv emulator emulator.bak
ln -s emulator64-arm emulator
```

No need to install any ia32 libs.

Comment: Thanks @blount. You are right no need to install any ia32 libs. Your saviour!

Comment: This helped me on kali linux, Thank you

Answer (score 10):

This is the answer http://astroelec.blogspot.com/

(using Debian)
Installing ia32-libs will no longer work as debian has moved to multiarch support.
Solution. Use Multiarch
Multiarch support makes installing libraries from the i386 distribution easy...

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

Now launch eclipse, and everything should now work just fine.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and John's answer worked perfect for me as I was running amd64 image
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386

Answer (score 2):

In my configuration, I have set up the virtual devices to use Intel Atom system image. Lawrence Angrave from the University Illinois [said in his Coursera androidapps101 course](https://class.coursera.org/androidapps101-002/lecture/view?lecture_id=31) that it will run faster than the ARM image. So this works for me:

```
mv emulator emulator_bak
ln -s emulator64-x86 emulator
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need install packages any more!

In directory tools, there are many types of `emulator`, while my computer works with `emulator64-arm`! My system is `Linux Mint 16 amd64`! Good luck!

```
./emulator64-arm @yxphone -sdcard yxsd -scale 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

it's easy,this is my solutions.
copy and paste, this lines in your terminal.

```
apt-get install libncurses5:i386 \
                   libstdc++6:i386 \
                   zlib1g:i386
```

good luck!!

Answer (score -1):

This might help

```
sudo aptitude install ia32-libs lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```